# Foundation object has no method foundation

Tags: object, zurb-foundation

I have a problem with my script ordering.

```
<head>
...    
<script src="layout/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="layout/js/foundation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="layout/js/foundation.tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="layout/js/foundation.reveal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="layout/js/jquery.modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
....

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I read many Solution of this problem but i don't find my bug :(..

Here is my Example Page with the Error in console:

http://davis-design.de/marktadresse/detailansicht.html

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
  <script>
          document.write('<script src=' +
          ('__proto__' in {} ? '<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/vendor/zepto") %>' :'<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/vendor/jquery")%>') +
  '.js><\/script>')
   </script>
  <script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/foundation.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript">   </script>
   <!--

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.alerts.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.cookie.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.forms.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.placeholder.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.interchange.js"></script>
  -->
 <script>
  $(document).foundation();
 </script>
```

Comment: must i to paste this <script>
              document.write('<script src=' +
              ('__proto__' in {} ? '<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/vendor/zepto") %>' :'<%=ResolveUrl("~/js/vendor/jquery")%>') +
      '.js><\/script>')
       </script>  in the head tag ??

Comment: before closing body tag </body>

Comment: i paste this <script>
          document.write('<script src=' +
       ('__proto__' in {} ? '<%=ResolveUrl("~/layout/js/jquery")%>') +
  '.js><\/script>')
   </script>
  <script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/layout/js/foundation.js") %>" type="text/javascript">   </script> but i have errors  --> http://davis-design.de/marktadresse/detailansicht.html

Comment: check the page source of this page example view-source:http://foundation.zurb.com/templates/blog.html 
and make sure you put correct path

Comment: So have now the same script ordering as your example page but i have continued the error :(

Comment: are you still have this issue ?